# How to setup Raid0 while having a ssd has main boot

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, raid, sata, raid-0

i tried setuping this up.

- SSD with windows to boot on
- 2 x 2T Hard Drive

When i switched my sata configuration in my bios to Raid to configure the other disks, my main boot ssd stoped working. It seems my ssd will only boot if the sata configuration is set to AHCI but i need to set the sata configuration to Raid to enable raid ?!?

What i did is setup the sata configuration back to AHCI and then i made software Raid 0 in windows.

Is this the proper way of doing so, do i still get the performances of a hardware raid ?

PS: Running Asus motherboard

Comment: possible duplicate of [RAID1 for storage only without reinstalling Windows](http://superuser.com/questions/733117/raid1-for-storage-only-without-reinstalling-windows)

Comment: The "proper" way is to set your BIOS to use RAID and then reinstall the OS using the RAID driver.

Comment: Event tho my os is on a ssd that is not in the raid ?

Comment: Yup. It's about the drivers for the drive _controller_, not the drives themselves.  Since they are all using the same controller they will all be affected when you change the mode the controller runs in (ie: AHCI to RAID).

Comment: Yes in that case my question a duplicate of the other one you linked. Thanks for the answer !

Comment: No problem, sorry I didn't have better news. :)